# Could the observed GZK limit exceeding cosmic rays be due to hawking radiation?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation, cosmic-rays

In this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742385/can-an-evaporating-black-hole-emit-protons-with-an-energy-beyond-the-gzk-limit), it was asked whether a black hole could emit protons with energies exceeding the [GZK limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit) via Hawking radiation, the answer given was yes. So I ask, what proportion if observed GZK exceeding cosmic rays could realistically have been produced by said process?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "black hole." If you count the accretion disk and/or the jets surrounding the SMBH at the center of a galaxy, then the answer is all of them. If you mean from a particle near the event horizon of any black hole, then the answer is probably 0.

Comment: And to be fair, the single answer in the linked question has no upvotes, which either means few people have seen it or no one can determine if it is right or wrong. I have my own suspicions that it is incorrect, but haven't spent enough time working it out. Hence, I probably would stick with saying it is 0%.

Comment: And now after I expressed my concern to the author of the linked answer that it wasn't convincing to me, they've deleted it.

Comment: And now I've posted a new answer that says the old answer is wrong, BHs wouldn't emit GZK limit protons (though it could accelerated existing protons, if it's sufficiently large).